# Where is Python support for PEM + RSA + DES3?

Tags: python, m2crypto, pycrypto, cryptography

I need a Python library that supports PEM files and both RSA signing and DES3 encryption. pycrypto doesn't seem to support PEM, and its mechanism for loading existing keys is undocumented and cryptic. m2crypto doesn't seem to support DES/DES3, oddly.

I've been running an openssl subprocess, but I'd rather have something built in and preferably fast. Does this exist?

(Failing that, I hesitate to ask, but are there high-level enough C apis available for this that I could write a special-purpose extension without killing myself/introducing vulns?)

Comment: M2Crypto supports DES3 encryption e.g., http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/howto.smime.html#ENCRYPT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the libraries mentioned in this overview:  [Comparison of Python cryptography modules](http://mikeivanov.com/pc/python-crypto.pdf)

Comment: Looks like I was wrong on m2crypto. Thanks for the PDF comparison chart.

Comment: @maciej: I'm sorry, I'm unable to locate another good link to the orignal document.  Perhaps this would be of use: http://www.scribd.com/doc/48627853/Python-Crypto or you could try contacting the poster for the original link at http://www.mikeivanov.com/